# Transitions in Petri nets

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have to crate a petri net for an homework assignment in university. In Tikz manual, I found a very useful tutorial on creating petri nets using Tikz/PGF. However, the example uses a different style for transitions, different from the one my professor prefers. He uses a style similar to the one on Wikipedia:

[image]

Notice that the transition (t) is represented by a small black bar. However, the example in the Tikz tutorial looks like this:

[image]

Here, transitions are represented by rectangualar boxes. Does anybody know how I can change the style of the transitions? I reckon that this can be done quite easily but please note that I'm a novice when it comes to Tikz and that I barely understood the source code for the petri net above.

Here is the source code from the Tikz guide: (I narrowed it down somewhat so it only includes the left petri net)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]

  \tikzstyle{place}=[circle,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20,minimum size=6mm]
  \tikzstyle{transition}=[rectangle,thick,draw=black!75,
              fill=black!20,minimum size=4mm]

    \node [place,tokens=1] (w1)                                    {};
    \node [place] (c1) [below of=w1]                      {};
    \node [place] (s)  [below of=c1,label=above:$s\le 3$] {};
    \node [place] (c2) [below of=s]                       {};
    \node [place,tokens=1] (w2) [below of=c2]                      {};

    \node [transition] (e1) [left of=c1] {}
      edge [pre,bend left]                  (w1)
      edge [post,bend right]                (s)
      edge [post]                           (c1);

    \node [transition] (e2) [left of=c2] {}
      edge [pre,bend right]                 (w2)
      edge [post,bend left]                 (s)
      edge [post]                           (c2);

    \node [transition] (l1) [right of=c1] {}
      edge [pre]                            (c1)
      edge [pre,bend left]                  (s)
      edge [post,bend right] node[swap] {2} (w1);

    \node [transition] (l2) [right of=c2] {}
      edge [pre]                            (c2)
      edge [pre,bend right]                 (s)
      edge [post,bend left]  node {2}       (w2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the `transition` style to, for example,

```
  transition/.style={
    rectangle,
    thick,
    fill=black,
    minimum width=8mm,
    inner ysep=2pt
    }
```

notice that I changed from the deprecated `\tikzstyle` to the more appropriate `\tikzset` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri}

  \tikzset{
  place/.style={
    circle,
    thick,
    draw=blue!75,
    fill=blue!20,
    minimum size=6mm
  },
  transition/.style={
    rectangle,
    thick,
    fill=black,
    minimum width=8mm,
    inner ysep=2pt
    }
  }            

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.3cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]


    \node [place,tokens=1] (w1)                                    {};
    \node [place] (c1) [below of=w1]                      {};
    \node [place] (s)  [below of=c1,label=above:$s\le 3$] {};
    \node [place] (c2) [below of=s]                       {};
    \node [place,tokens=1] (w2) [below of=c2]                      {};

    \node [transition] (e1) [left of=c1] {}
      edge [pre,bend left]                  (w1)
      edge [post,bend right]                (s)
      edge [post]                           (c1);

    \node [transition] (e2) [left of=c2] {}
      edge [pre,bend right]                 (w2)
      edge [post,bend left]                 (s)
      edge [post]                           (c2);

    \node [transition] (l1) [right of=c1] {}
      edge [pre]                            (c1)
      edge [pre,bend left]                  (s)
      edge [post,bend right] node[swap] {2} (w1);

    \node [transition] (l2) [right of=c2] {}
      edge [pre]                            (c2)
      edge [pre,bend right]                 (s)
      edge [post,bend left]  node {2}       (w2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code a little bit to make it similar than the one that you showed at the beginning. Try it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=0.96]{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,automata,petri}

\tikzset{
place/.style={
circle,
thick,
draw=black,
%fill=blue!20,
minimum size=6mm
  },
  transition/.style={
    rectangle,
    thick,
        draw=black,
    minimum width=8mm,
    inner ysep=2pt
    }
  }     
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,>=stealth',bend angle=45,auto]


    \node [place,tokens=2] (w1) [label=above:$N$]                    {};
        \node [place,inner sep=0pt, minimum size=0pt] (blank) [left of=w1] {};
    \node [place,tokens=2] (c1) [left of=blank, label=above:$H$]     {};

    \node [transition] (e1) [below of=blank, label=right:$s$] {}
      edge [pre]                  (w1)
      edge [pre]    node{2}       (c1);
    \node [place] (d1) [below of=e1, label=below:$N_2H$] {}
      edge [pre]                  (e1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```